# $\sum_{d|n, d>0} (\sigma(d)/d)\mu(n/d))=1/n$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function

> We want to show
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{d|n,\  d>0}(\sigma(d)/d)\cdot \mu(n/d) =1/n ,
> \end{align}
>   where $\sigma(m)$ denotes the sum of all positive divisors of $m$ and where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

The hint is that we can use the formula $\sigma(n)/n=\sum_{d|n,\ d>0} 1/d$.

I tried to pull out (1/d) from the sum and then convoluted the function to get 
\begin{align}
\sum_{d|n,\  d>0}(\sigma(d)/d)\cdot \mu(n/d)
=\sigma(n)/n\sum_{d|n,\ d>0} (\sigma(n/d))\cdot\mu(d)
\end{align}
and then tried to get 
$$\sum_{d|n,\ d>0} (\sigma(n/d))\cdot\mu(d)=1/\sigma(n)$$

But I can't figure out how to get there.  Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)?  It's all you need.

Comment: I know the formula but I don't get what to do with that

Comment: If $g(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$, then $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d)\mu(n/d)$. Let $f(n) = 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to MSE.

Write $ \frac{σ(n)}{n} = (U*f)(n)$ , where $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$, and $U(n)=1$ for all n.

You are then asked to find $((U*f) * (μ))$.
Dirichlet convolution is associative and commutative, therefore, $(U*f) * (μ)= f*(U*μ)$, and $U* \mu$ is the identity of the Dirichlet convolution, therefore overall we get $f(n)$, as required.

(here * means dirichlet convolution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution))

Comment: Why can you say $\sigma(n)/n=(1/n)*(1)?$  I'm not seeing the connection

Comment: That's because of the hint given to you, ie $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}= \sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d}$ which is equal to $ U * f$ using the convolution notation.

Comment: @mupin By definition $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d | n} d = \sum_{d | n} n/d$ so $\sigma(n)/n = \sum_{d | n} 1/d= 1 \ast (1/n)$. Then $(\sigma(n)/n) \ast \mu =\sum_{l | n} \mu(n/l)\sum_{d | l} 1/d = \sum_{d | n} 1/d \sum_{l | n, d | l} \mu(n/l)$ with $k = n/l$ it is $=  \sum_{d | n} \frac1d \sum_{k | n, k | n/d} \mu(k)= \sum_{d | n} \frac1d  1_{n/d= 1} = 1/n$